# Tkinter solid border button

Tags: python, tkinter, graphics

I want to display a solid border in grey beetween each button but the `highlightbackground`,`highlightcolor`, `borderwith` don't seem to be working.

However the `text` and `relief:"solid"`  is working in each button.

There is my code :

```
import tkinter as tk

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        lbl = tk.Label(top_frame, text="",
                       font="Helvetica 45 bold",
                       height=2,
                       width=5,
                       bg="#41B77F",
                       highlightbackground="grey",
                       highlightcolor="grey",
                       relief="solid",
                       highlightthickness=1)
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, xy=[x, y]: get_cordinate(xy))
        lbl.grid(row=x, column=y, padx=2, pady=2)

        dict_labels = {"xy": [x, y], "symbol": "", "label": lbl, "ticked": False}
        list_labels.append(dict_labels)
```

[image: Tictactoe]

Comment: create minimal working code which we could run. You could also add image because it may gives different result on different systems (Windows, Linux, MacOS) And maybe create image with expected result.

Comment: how about black background in `top_frame` and `lbl.grid(..., padx=2, pady=2)` - it can looks like border between buttons.

Comment: It's looking better, I added ```relief="solid"``` and added ```lbl.grid(..., padx=2, pady=2)``` but i can't change the color of the border, it's staying black even if i change the ```highlightcolor``` to green

Comment: maybe you need `borderwidth=0` to remove it. What if you use `Button()` instead of `Label()` ?

Comment: You cannot change the color of the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried changing the black border but it doesn't change though it works if I change from `Label` to `Frame` so you can put your label inside the frame and change the `highlightbackground`, `highlightcolor`, `borderwith` of the frame.

*Here's what I did*

```py
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        con_frame = tk.Frame(top_frame,bg="#41B77F",
                       highlightbackground="grey",
                       highlightcolor="grey",
                       relief="solid",
                       highlightthickness=3)
        lbl = tk.Label(con_frame, text="", 
                        height=2, width=5, 
                        bg="#41B77F", 
                        font="Helvetica 45 bold",
                        bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        lbl.grid(sticky='nsew')
        lbl.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, xy=[x, y]: get_cordinate(xy))
        con_frame.grid(row=x, column=y, padx=2, pady=2)

        dict_labels = {"xy": [x, y], "symbol": "", "label": lbl, "ticked": False}
        list_labels.append(dict_labels)
```

[image]